# Which is right way to map few server models into one domains?

Tags: android, rx-java, clean-architecture, rx-kotlin

My server api looks like this:

```
data class ArticleDTO(val id: Int, val title: String, val typeId: Int)
data class Type(val id: Int, val name: String) 

interface API {
    fun getArticles(): Single<List<ArticleDTO>>
    fun getTypes(): Single<List<Type>>
}
```

And I have one model which I use in UI:

```
data class Article(val title: String, val typeName: String)
```

I created map method:

```
fun ArticleDTO.toArticle(type: Type) = Article(this.title, typeName = type.name)
```

And in the repository class I did this:

```
fun getArticles() =
    Observables.combineLatest(api.getArticles().toObservable(), api.getTypes().toObservable())
        .flatMap {
            Observable.just(it.first.map { articleDTO ->
                articleDTO
                    .toArticle(it.second.find { type -> type.id == articleDTO.typeId }!!)
            })
        }
```

Is there a way to do it better?

And what if my api will looks like this:

```
interface API {
    fun getArticles(): Single<List<ArticleDTO>>
    fun getTypes(typeId: Int): Single<Type>
}
```

Comment: `Which is right way to...` does it work ? does it not work ? what is wrong with your current code ?

Comment: Its work, but looks weird, don't you think so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get rid of `flatMap` and `Observable.just`

```
fun getArticles() = Observables.combineLatest(api.getArticles().toObservable(), api.getTypes().toObservable())
        .map { (dtos, types) ->
            dtos.map { articleDTO ->
                articleDTO
                    .toArticle(types.find { type -> type.id == articleDTO.typeId }!!)
            }
        }
```

Comment: How about that?

`fun getArticles() =
 Single.zip(api.getArticles(), api.getTypes(), { dtos, types ->
  dtos.items.map { articleDTO ->
   articleDTO.toArticle(types.find { it.id == articleDTO.typeId })}})`

Comment: thats even better :)